# Non uniqueness of center of the Banach-Mazur compactum

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, convex-geometry

In "The Banach-Mazur distance to the cube and the Dvoretzky-Rogers factorization" Szarek and Bourgain prove a proportional Dvoretzky-Rogers factorization :

Given $1>\delta>0$ , there exists $C=C(\delta)>0$ such that for any  normed space X of dimension $n$, there exists $x_1,..x_m$, with $m= \lfloor\delta n\rfloor$ such that for all scalars $t_1,..,t_m$ we have :

$$\max_{j\leq m}\vert t_j \vert \leq \vert\vert \sum_{j\leq m}t_jx_j\vert\vert\leq C\left(\sum_{j\leq m} t_j^2\right)^{1/2}$$

In other words, there exists a subspace $H$ of dimension $m = \lfloor\delta n\rfloor$ and an operator $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^m)$ such that :

$$\frac{1}{C}TB^m_2 \subset B_X \cap H \subset TB_\infty^m $$
But they affirm (and other textbooks do) that this result (or the proof of it) also implies that for $m=\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ and $Y=l_2^m \oplus l_1^{n-m}$ then any space $X$ is at Banach-Mazur distance of $Y$ at most $C\sqrt{n}$. This implies that $Y$ is an asymptotic center of the Banach-Mazur compactum. As we can easily see that $d(Y,l_2^n) \geq \sqrt{n/2}$ it implies "non uniqueness" of the centers of the compactum.
Can anyone explain to me the proof of the above fact, which I can't find fully written anywhere ?

Comment: A technical remark: given any $1>\delta>0$ and a dimension $n$, $\delta n$ can fail to be integer and then it is not clear, what is $m$.

Comment: The argument is given in more detail in the middle of page 53 in 
Szarek, S. J. "On the geometry of the Banach-Mazur compactum." Functional Analysis. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg, 1991. 48-59.